# Xamarin IOS card.io dll integeration native linking failed while build in Adhoc or Appstore

Tags: ios, xamarin, card.io

I'm creating IOS app using xamarin I integerated card.io in my app by adding card.io dll in references Its working fine while debugging If I moved to Adhoc or Appstore it will throw an native linking failed error MT5210.

Card.IO's guide states I need to add -lstdc++ to "other linker flags" in Xcode but I don't know where should I put this in Xamarin Studio's options

I need help for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Xcode "other linker flags" in Xamarin by setting the "Additional mtouch arguments" field. Put the following value in "Additional mtouch arguments" text field.

-cxx -gcc_flags "-lstdc++"

Location of "Additional mtouch arguments" field : Right click on project => Options => iOS Build.